# Should the gender tag be split?

Tags: discussion

I think the [gender](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag is currently serving more than one purpose, but I don't have a clear statement of what the appropriate tags should be. Also, I am looking for some sort of community support, so I am not imposing my own definitions/word boundaries on others.

The current tag includes 95 questions about:

- Biological sex differences:

  - [Is 1,7% of the population born intersex?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38421/is-1-7-of-the-population-born-intersex)
  - [Can you determine the gender of a baby by the shape of the mother's belly?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/can-you-determine-the-gender-of-a-baby-by-the-shape-of-the-mothers-belly)
  - [Are men smarter than women?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/are-men-smarter-than-women)
  - [Can human males produce milk?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9168/can-human-males-produce-milk)
- LGBTIA issues (especially transgender issues)

  - [Does gender reassignment surgery increase quality of life of transgender individuals?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/does-gender-reassignment-surgery-increase-quality-of-life-of-transgender-individ?s=4|1.5902)
  - [Do 80% of gender-dysphoric children grow up deciding not to change their gender?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36327/do-80-of-gender-dysphoric-children-grow-up-deciding-not-to-change-their-gender?s=6|0.9542)
  - [Do only 1-4% of the population self-report/self-identify as homosexual?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/do-only-1-4-of-the-population-self-report-self-identify-as-homosexual/30494?s=7|0.8666#30494)
- Society and Gender issues (especially gender-equality issues):

  - [Was pink a boy color and blue a girl color prior to the 20th century?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38606/was-pink-a-boy-color-and-blue-a-girl-color-prior-to-the-20th-century)
  - [Does having more women in a group increase its collective intelligence?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38033/does-having-more-women-in-a-group-increase-its-collective-intelligence)
  - [Has Saudi Arabia announced plans for a women-only city?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/has-saudi-arabia-announced-plans-for-a-women-only-city)
  - [Are women underpaid relative to men?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/908/are-women-underpaid-relative-to-men)
  - [Boys and girls and co-education: what works best?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/boys-and-girls-and-co-education-what-works-best)

It strikes me that these are quite different classes of question, and the tag should be split, but I am not convinced that my taxonomy is the best one, that my names are right, or that this isn't all just one person's opinion.

Any suggestions?

*This question was inspired by [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38317827#38317827).*

Comment: Possibly related: there's a race and a racism tag IIRC.

Comment: Is the amount of Qs high enough that splitting will *meaningfully* help an expert search? at 96, it seems that it's small enough to not necessarily in need of more granularity to allow effective filtering. And having a single tag eliminates the need for trying to "correctly" tag with 1 of 3 new ones.